# How to validate unique together constraint in Tastypie?

Tags: python, django, validation, unique, tastypie

I have a model with unique_togeter = True and i'm using a ModelForm to validate it.

## models.py

```
class Restrict(BaseModel):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.ForeignKey('title')
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, default=datetime.now())
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=datetime.now())

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["id"]
        db_table = "editor_restrict"
        app_label = "geral"
        unique_together = ('user', 'title')
```

## resources.py

```
class TitleResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = Titulo.objects.all()
        always_return_data = True
        fields = ['name']


class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name']
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        always_return_data = True
        filtering = {
            'username': ALL,
        }


class RestrictResource(ModelResource):
    user = fields.ForeignKey(UserResource, attribute='user', full=True)
    title = fields.ForeignKey(TitleResource, attribute='title')

    class Meta:
        authentication = Authentication()
        authorization = Authorization()
        queryset = Restrict.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'restrict'
        always_return_data = True
        fields = ['user', 'title', 'active']
        serializer = Serializer()
        validation = FormValidation(form_class=RestrictForm)
        filtering = {
            'user': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
        }
```

That's working nicely when i do a POST like that:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST --data '{"active": true, "title": "/api/v1/titulo/16/", "user":"/api/v1/user/52831/"}' 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/restrict/'
```

The response is Status Code: 400 BAD REQUEST, as expected.

BUT with the full user like this:

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -X POST --data '{"active": true, "title": "/api/v1/titulo/16/", "user": {"username": "johnny@mail.com", "email": "johnny@mail.com", "first_name": "Johnny"}}' 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/restrict/'
```

I get the TypeError Exception int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict' from django.

The UserResource is working just fine too in all the CRUD.

If i take off the unique_together from Model this POST works just fine too.

I tryed debug but i can't figure out what's happening.

The question is: How can i validate this case and return the correct response?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Possible issue: unique together converts to unique constraint in mysql, and it allows duplicates if at least one of the columns is null.
2. Add title default value, or restrict to not null (if you will alow null it may cause 1.).
3. Try to add some debug info to RestrictResource save, so you will see which dict appears in foregn int field.